# How to count factor and no double count in the same year

Tags: r, count, data.table

i have a data like following, i want to do the cumulative count the occurrence of name,but the count number can't be count twice in the same year.

```
mydata<-
data.table(name=c("hon","hon","hon","acer","acer","acer","acer","acer"),
year=c(1991,1991,1992,1981,1982,1983,1983,1983),
count=c(1,1,2,1,2,3,3,3))
setDT(mydata)
```

my initial solution is

```
mydata[,mcount:=1:.N,by=name]
```

but it will double count in the same year. 
any suggestion is welcome. thx advance.

Comment: `mydata[, mycount := cumsum(!duplicated(year)), by = name]`?

Comment: @docendodiscimus  I didn't know that the OP wanted the expected output in 'count'.  Anyway, I posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `match` after grouping by 'name'

```
mydata[, mycount := match(year, unique(year)), name]
mydata
#   name year count mycount
#1:  hon 1991     1       1
#2:  hon 1991     1       1
#3:  hon 1992     2       2
#4: acer 1981     1       1
#5: acer 1982     2       2
#6: acer 1983     3       3
#7: acer 1983     3       3
#8: acer 1983     3       3
```

---

Or another option is `factor` with `levels` specified as `unique` elements of 'year' after grouping by 'name' and then convert it to `integer`

```
mydata[, mycount := as.integer(factor(year, levels = unique(year))), name]
```

Comment: ask if i want to count start with zero, how show i do.
mydata[,mycount:=mycount-1] show NA @@?

Comment: @changjx  Just subtract 1 i.e. `mydata[, mycount := match(year, unique(year))-1, name]`  For me, it is giving the expected output i.e. `mydata$mycount
#[1] 0 0 1 0 1 2 2 2`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want a cumulative count of distinct years per name. To do this, you can use `duplicated` on the year column, negate it, and `cumsum`:

```
mydata[, mycount := cumsum(!duplicated(year)), by = name]

#    name year count mycount
# 1:  hon 1991     1       1
# 2:  hon 1991     1       1
# 3:  hon 1992     2       2
# 4: acer 1981     1       1
# 5: acer 1982     2       2
# 6: acer 1983     3       3
# 7: acer 1983     3       3
# 8: acer 1983     3       3
```